# How can I use my SQL query in the cursor query?

Tags: sql-server

I want to get the output by returning in the course question against the values from the following SQL query question. I want to record this print. How can I do that? Thank you for your help.

SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    [NoMatchExplanation],
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    err.CustomerBank
GROUP BY 
   (NoMatchExplanation)
```

Cursor query:

```
DECLARE cr_Read CURSOR FOR
   SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'err'

DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(100)

OPEN cr_Read

FETCH NEXT FROM cr_Read INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO etl.ErrorTable VALUES (@name)

    FETCH NEXT FROM cr_Read INTO @name
END

CLOSE cr_Read
DEALLOCATE cr_Read
```

Comment: you dont need a cursor for this. Check Ruslan's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do like this:

```
INSERT INTO etl.ErrorTable
   SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'err';
```